# ScrollViewer with ItemsControl not working

Tags: wpf

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Height="100">
        <ItemsControl Name="icReviews" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Height="300">
            <ItemsControl.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" >
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFFF9900" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FFDD4400" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </ItemsControl.Background>

            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="3" Width="1712" Height="300"></UniformGrid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>


            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition ></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextElement.FontFamily="FangSong" TextElement.FontSize="15"  TextElement.FontWeight="Bold" TextElement.Foreground="Blue">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Subject}" Foreground="White" TextElement.FontSize="15" TextElement.FontFamily="FangSong" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5,5"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Review}" Foreground="White" TextElement.FontSize="15" TextElement.FontFamily="FangSong" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5,5"></TextBlock>
                                <WrapPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="Posted by : " Foreground="White" Margin="5,5" TextElement.FontSize="15"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Username}" Foreground="White" TextElement.FontSize="15" TextElement.FontFamily="FangSong" Margin="5,5"></TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </WrapPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

I have now edited my code with the height attribute of scrollviewer. I still cant see any scrollbars

Comment: Hi sly, can you define "not working" a bit more? I'm not clear about what problem you're experiencing

Comment: ScrollViewer doesnt show up . No matter where I place the scrollviewer it doesnt show

Comment: Are you giving your `ScrollViewer` a height, or constraining it within a panel that limits the size of its children? If the height is not limited in some way, there's no reason for the ScrollViewer to show the scrollbars as it can grow to whatever height it needs. You can test it by setting the `VerticalSCrollBarVisibility` and `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Visible` to make sure they always show up.

Comment: I have edited the code with the height

Comment: Well done Rachel. I have solved it with the height property. Thanks

Comment: glad to hear :) I posted that as an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you giving your `ScrollViewer` a height, or constraining it within a panel that limits the height of its children?

If the height is not limited in some way, there's no reason for the `ScrollViewer` to show the scrollbars as it can grow to whatever height it needs to display its children.

You can test it by setting the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` and `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Visible` to see where your `ScrollViewer` actually is, and if this is the case then you can fix the issue by either seting the `ScrollViewer.Height` to a value, or wrapping it in a container that does not allow its children to grow to whatever size they want.

Comment: Adding a MaxHeight to my ScrollViewer fixed the scrolling issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a `ControlTemplate` for `ItemsPresenter` that contains a `ScrollViewer`. I don't believe it includes one by default...